# How to highlight a cell using the hex color value within the cell (but for the latest edition of Excel)

Tags: excel, colors, hex, spreadsheet

I want to try and create a spreadsheet for a coloured item collecting database. It would be extremely useful if when I input the hex code, the cell with the hex code in it is filled with the same colour as the hex. This is so that I can compare different coloured items and mix and match similar looking colours. [Spreadsheet currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVna8.png)

If anyone knows how I can fill the cells in the Hex column to be the same colour as the hex written in the cell please let me know!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place look for suggestions, tips and best-practices. It's encourage to start with something and seek help if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeSelectedCellsBackground()
    Dim cell
    For Each cell in Selection
        ChangeCellBackground cell
    Next
End Sub

Sub ChangeCellBackground(cell)
    Dim hexStr as string
    hexStr = cell.Value

    Dim r as string
    Dim g as string
    Dim b as string
    r = Mid(hexStr, 1, 2)
    g = Mid(hexStr, 3, 2)
    b = Mid(hexStr, 5, 2)
    
    cell.Interior.Color = RGB(CInt("&H" & r), CInt("&H" & g), CInt("&H" & b))
End Sub
```